# Merge multiple pathcollections made by different scatter plots in one figure subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to remove some of the points created by the scatter plot based on [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/lasso_selector_demo_sgskip.html). The problem arises when I have multiple scatter plots in one subplot and therefore many PathCollections. I'm trying to make a single PathCollection that includes the points from all of the scatter plots. How can I achieve this?

Here is a minimal code:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector


class RemoveButton:

    def __init__(self, ax, collection, alpha_other=0.3):
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.collection = collection
        self.alpha_other = alpha_other

        self.xys = collection.get_offsets()
        self.Npts = len(self.xys)

        # Ensure that we have separate colors for each object
        self.fc = collection.get_facecolors()
        if len(self.fc) == 0:
            raise ValueError('Collection must have a facecolor')
        elif len(self.fc) == 1:
            self.fc = np.tile(self.fc, (self.Npts, 1))

        self.lasso = LassoSelector(ax, onselect=self.onselect)
        self.ind = []

    def onselect(self, verts):
        path = Path(verts)
        self.ind = np.nonzero(path.contains_points(self.xys))[0]
        self.fc[:, -1] = self.alpha_other
        self.fc[self.ind, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.lasso.disconnect_events()
        self.fc[:, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    data = np.random.rand(100, 2)
    data2 = np.random.rand(100, 2)

    subplot_kw = dict(xlim=(0, 1), ylim=(0, 1), autoscale_on=False)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw)

    pc1 = ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], s=80)
    pc2 = ax.scatter(data2[:, 0], data2[:, 1], s=80)

    pts = pc1

    selector = RemoveButton(ax=ax, collection=pts)

    def accept(event):
        if event.key == "enter":
            for p in selector.xys[selector.ind]:
                offsets: np.ma.MaskedArray = pts.get_offsets()
                if p in offsets:
                    offsets_list = offsets.tolist()
                    offsets_list.remove(p.tolist())
                    pts.set_offsets(np.ma.MaskedArray(offsets_list))

            fig.canvas.draw()

            selector.disconnect()
            ax.set_title("")

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", accept)
    ax.set_title("Press enter to accept selected points.")

    plt.show()
```

As you can see, I'm only passing one PathCollection to RemoveButton Class, and it works. but I need to be able to remove points from any of the scatter plots I want.

Answer (score 0):

well, actually I could append/extend the second one's data to the first one, and just run scatter() one time. This way you have just one pathcollection...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This technique can be useful for combining PathCollections from scatter plots on different axes, even though in the questioner's case it's possible to avoid generating multiple collections. As a complete demo, here's how to create a figure legend based on multiple subplotted scatters in matplotlib 3.7.1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PathCollection

data1 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
data2 = np.random.rand(100, 3)

# Create scatter plots on separate axes
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
s1 = axs[0].scatter(data1[:, 0], data1[:, 1], s=data1[:, 2]*100, alpha=0.6)
s2 = axs[1].scatter(data2[:, 0], data2[:, 1], s=data2[:, 2]*100, alpha=0.6)

# Combine the PathCollections into a single one
# get_paths() returns a list, get_sizes() returns an array. They must be
# concatenated differently
s = PathCollection(s1.get_paths() + s2.get_paths(),
                   np.concatenate((s1.get_sizes(), s2.get_sizes())),
                  )

# Now assemble a legend from the new PathCollection based on sizes.
# Note that I'm copying the color from the first collection
handles, labels = s.legend_elements(prop="sizes", color=s1.get_facecolor())

# Build the legend on the figure
fig.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right')
```

[image: Resulting figure]